# Using ! (exclamation mark) in CSS property name

Tags: css

I've seen this used once or twice now, where `!` mark is put before property name. For example:

```
!overflow: hidden;
```

(also, [see here](http://blog.proto.io/wp-content/themes/richardshepherd-TwentyTenFive-ed29e68/css/publicsite.css))

Can anyone shed some light on what its purpose is?

Comment: Spelling mistakes maybe? I've never seen or heard of exclamation marks in a CSS attribute

Comment: I sometimes need exclamation marks while *working* on CSS. Does that count?

Comment: Some interesting samples from the given link: `f!loat: left;` and `m!argin-right: 15px; p!adding-left: 31px; h!eight: 26px; l!ine-height: 26px;`

Comment: That looks like a CSS hack in order to address specific browser versions.

Comment: Never seen such a thing... Who made this code?

Comment: I'm going to guess it's an IE hack, where the exclamation mark is filtered out probably without causing parse errors of the property.

Comment: The css seems to be in relation to the TwentyTenFive wordpress theme. However, they don't use such things on their own website's css: http://www.twentytenfive.com/css/style.css :D

Comment: Possibly a varient on this [IE 5-6 backslash hack](http://www.webteacher.ws/2005/01/22/490/), since the placement of the exclamation marks is similar

Comment: @Dre Yes it is, I came to the same conclusion during a short investigation :)

Comment: But yes I just tried it with every single IE I could imagine and I couldn't get it to work. So what kind of setup could it be addressing?

Comment: IE5-6... Do you have a test case set up publicly on jsfiddle? I can run those tests easily but I am kinda lazy ~_~

Comment: @sg3s: You realize jsFiddle doesn't even work on those versions?

Comment: @BoltClock The [result view](http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/eab53/2/embedded/result/) does.

Comment: I tried it with this one: http://fiddle.jshell.net/xdfB6/2/show/

Comment: Here are [my test results](http://imgur.com/a/6TzSq), yeah it doesn't seem to do anything (IE6 virtualized with spoon.net on win8).

Comment: @sg3s: Oh yeah. I forgot you could link to that directly.

Comment: Come to think of it, it's looking more and more like a variation on the IE5-6 hack. It may have something to do with code completion or syntax highlighting in whatever IDE he's using, as the \ is an escape character.

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any information about it but it is apparently a hack.  At least Chrome will not apply the styles where the property names have exclamation marks in them.  What's interesting to me is that at least for the styles I checked, the exact same style is applied by *another* stylesheet except correctly -- so maybe it's just a straight up mistake.

Comment: Perhaps a CSS preprocessor/compiler bug?

Comment: It's been made a few too many times in that stylesheet to be a mistake :) I might pop Richard Shepherd an email, and see what he comes back with.